# Product does not import with csv in Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have to tried to import a product in Magento 1.9.2.2. It gets imported without errors, but it's not showing in the backend admin panel, what the exact issue is in my csv.

I have attached my export csv below; please check it and let me know what I am doing wrong in csv.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/93h8u4uv5kr2dlp/export.2.csv?dl=0

Comment: The question should include the CSV structure and some data (can be sample data) in the body itself rather than linking to an external file hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv template is totally wrong, please look on proper example template [link](http://blog.maximusbusiness.com/download/3259/). You could just extend it and fill with your data.